# Kernel Crash - kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000ff8179b9

Tags: linux-kernel, server-crashes, kernel-panic, oracle-linux

One of my Oracle Linux 6.5 Server running Oracle ASM/GRID experienced a kernel crash, it didn't respond i have performed a hard reboot.

Server is Oracle Linux 6.5, kernel 2.6.39-400.214.3.el6uek.x86_64, 32GB RAM, 35GB swap, also there is no warning on hardware side.

The logs on /var/log/messages:

```
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000ff8179b9
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: IP: [<ffffffff8105adc1>] task_rq_lock+0x61/0xb0
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: PGD 8020af067 PUD 0
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: CPU 8

Message from syslogd@srvx-prod at Apr 19 08:22:14 ...
kernel:Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: Modules linked in: oracleacfs(P)(U)      oracleadvm(P)(U) oracleoks(P)(U) oracleasm autofs4 sunrpc cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq freq_table mperf ip6t_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_state nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables ipv6 dm_queue_length scsi_dh_alua dm_multipath uinput microcode pcspkr ghes i2c_i801 i2c_core iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support hed ioatdma dca i7core_edac edac_core sg enic ext4 mbcache jbd2 sd_mod crc_t10dif fnic libfcoe libfc scsi_transport_fc scsi_tgt mptsas mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_sas wmi dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel:
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: Pid: 5139, comm: crsd.bin Tainted: P            2.6.39-400.214.3.el6uek.x86_64 #1 Cisco Systems Inc N20-B6625-1/N20-B6625-1
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8105adc1>]  [<ffffffff8105adc1>] task_rq_lock+0x61/0xb0
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8807db413de8  EFLAGS: 00010046
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: RAX: 00000000ff8179b9 RBX: ffff8807db540300 RCX: 000000000000c388
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: RDX: 000000000000f646 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: ffff88086f2d2180
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: RBP: ffff8807db413e18 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: ffff88086f2d2180
Apr 19 08:22:14 srvx-prod kernel: R13: 0000000000012180 R14: ffff8807db413e30 R15: ffff8807db540ad0
```

Any help pls.

Comment: Check is there is any hardware errors such as bad ram etc. **[Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged** normally mean something wrong with hardware.